# premake5 Is it possible to generate a project without a workspace?

Tags: build, project, premake

I have project A which is used in two different workspaces. I would like to generate it "standalone" and then reference it using externalproject in both my workspaces, but I'm unable to do this: premake5 complains if I try to generate a project without a workspace.

So right now, my solution is to include project A in workspace 1, and using externalproject in the workspace 2, or generating project A for each workspace, or create a "fake" workspace to generate it alone and then discard the extra.

Is there a way to simply generate a project without a workspace ? If not, for those who encounters this issue, how did you solve it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Premake currently requires a solution/workspace. Though you could always code your script to delete the solution after it is created, maybe something like:

```
premake.override(premake.main, 'postAction', function(base)
    os.remove('MySolution.sln')
end)
```